# Visual studio code: CTRL + B => "edt " at the top bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to figure out how to toggle the side bar, and apparently `ctrl + b` is the way to do it, but when I perform it, it opens up the that input bar in the middle of the top portion of the editor, just below the menu bar, with "edt " (including the space) typed in.

My keybindings.json file shows that I should ctrl+b should indeed toggle the side menu.

If I delete the "edt " and press ctrl+b, it just regenerates it.

Anyone know how to fix this? Nothing shows up on Google either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl + b` is bound to `Add Function Breakpoint` by default. You can edit the shortcuts from `File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 0):

`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` will show you a list of shortcuts.

You can search for `Toggle Side Bar Visibility` or `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility` to see what the current shortcut bindings are, and edit them.

Mine were also showing the `edt` behavior you described, and were set to accept `Ctrl + \` as well as `Ctrl + K Ctrl + B` for toggling the side bar visibility. `Ctrl + \` may be worth trying out if you do not want to go through the hassle of finding a new non-clashing key combination to set as the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `edt`, it is because `ctrl+b` is bound by default to `View: Show All Editors By Appearance`.

As others have mentioned, use `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` (or find it in the command palette with `ctrl+p`), then search for "Show All Editors By Appearance" and remove that key binding.

You may also remove any other `ctrl+b` bindings there, if they're in your way by searching for "ctrl+b".

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+B is normally worked in toggling sidebar in Visual Code, but some extensions prevent it, because ctrl+b is used in these extensions as a shortcut.

To solve this problem:

You should go to

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

and then, you will change the shortcuts used as ctrl + b

> View: Toggle Side Bar Visibility